# Add ipdb tab autocomplete to VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, atom-editor, ipdb

I used to use Atom until Microsoft mercifully killed it.
I tried other editors, learned a lot of Vim and NeoVim this year, but in the end I feel the most comfortable with what I'm used to and Zed is still being developed, so I resigned myself to VSCode.

At this point I got used or customized most things but there is one thing I'm not sure how to go about.

In Atom I had a very convenient way to add an interactive debugger line to my python code:

I would type `ipdb` and hit tab and I would get `import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()`

This behavior is not default in VSCode and I would like to learn how I can emulate that. There must be a config setting where I can edit tab suggestions, but where is it?

Thank you,
Alex